# How do I DownGrade Flutter Version

Tags: flutter, flutter2.0

I intalled flutter 2.0.4 ,but now i'm facing a lot of problem working with it. I don't know my older version number, but I don't want to flutter 2.0.4. It's really a horrible experience.

Comment: Well, one option would be to uninstall Flutter 2, then install whatever previous version you'd like.

Comment: how do i do that. I use windows and VS Code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to downgrade to specific version then use

```
flutter downgrade <version> (like v.1.0.2)
```

If you want all the previous versions list

```
flutter downgrade
```

After this just run

```
flutter doctor
```

Comment: how old is flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.7

Comment: It was released on 27 Jan 2020, you can use 1.22.6 it was the last released before the 2.0 release

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to download the the version you want and replace the flutter sdk installation folder it with the doownloaded one.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=windows